# How to accept exact float values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently developing a evaluation class. This class have 4 topic fields. Eg: Technique and will accept only a range of values:

(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, ... 5)

There's a way to create a validation where only will accept this values, besides see if the attribute value is on a array?

```
def some_name
 a_values = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0]
 !a_values.includes?(self.technique)
end
```

Comment: Did you read about [custom validator in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)?

Comment: Why don't you just use the [`validates inclusion`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set an inclusion validation and use a ruby range with steps to make the array of values less hardcoded https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of

```
validates_inclusion_of :technique, in: (1..5).step(0.5)
```

Comment: I doubt the validator accepts an `Enumerator` instance.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin the doc says `:in - An enumerable object of available items. This can be supplied as a proc, lambda or symbol which returns an enumerable. If the enumerable is a numerical range the test is performed with Range#cover?, otherwise with include?. When using a proc or lambda the instance under validation is passed as an argument.`, maybe it need to be wrapped inside a Proc.

Comment: `#to_a` would suffice.

Comment: The doc examples show this `validates_inclusion_of :age, in: 0..99` as a valid argument for :in.

Comment: Let me guess: it’s because `(0..99).class #⇒ Range` but `(1..5).step(0.5).class #⇒ Enumerator`.

Comment: Just tested on a project and it does accept (1..5).step(0.5). The validation works just right with the Enumerator.

Comment: The doc says "an enumerable object" and both Range, Enumerator and Array all includes the Enumerable module and the three objects does works. I guess any object that includes Enumerable is valid (and also Proc, Lambdas and symbols that returns an object that includes Enumerable).